# Qt - How to put existing widgets and qscrollbar inside a QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a newbie in Qt.
I'm making a notepad with a ribbon:

[image]

And I wanted to make appear a QScrollBar when I resize the Window and I know that I have to use a QScrollArea for it.
My question is, how do I add existing widgets to a QScrollArea and make appear a QScrollBar when needed?

Comment: [QScrollArea::setWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) (If you have multiple children intended, make a `QWidget` and set the layout with the multiple children to it. The `QScrollArea` should be part of your widget hierarchy from the beginning. That scrollbars do not appear when not needed is subject of the scroll bar policies (which can be separately set for hor. and vert. scrollbar). That's explained e.g. in the intro of [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#details).

Comment: @Sheff's Cat Hi, can I ask you how do I add a layout? And how do I put the push buttons in the same position inside the layout?

Comment: @Sheff's Cat can you give me some help please

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me like your widgets are aligned in any form of layout. From designer, these button at the top allow you to put widgets in layouts:

[image: Qt Creator layout buttons]

Once your widgets are in their necessary layouts, make a new QScrollArea (either by doing `QScrollArea *myArea = new QScrollArea()` and adding it to a layout manually, or by dragging and dropping it in the designer). It should be as drag and drop as everything else you've encountered so far. You will want to set the vertical scroll policy to never scroll and set the contents margins of the scroll area's widget to 0.

But this begs the question, how savvy are you with GUI programming outside of Qt? You will run into a lot of obstacles from here on out if you can't grasp the concept of layouts and so on.

In case you don't know how layouts work, I suggest you look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). It's a good rule of thumb to check the docs and look for existing questions before asking. Manually setting the X and Y of widgets is a long-gone practice.

Comment: Hi, I tried but the position of the pushbuttons and their sizes gets weird while I wanted to make it stay the same. I didn't find anything in the documentation, I will have a look again.

Comment: You can set the horizontal size policy of all the buttons to fixed instead of minimum. As for the positioning, you can control that with spacing and contents margins.